# How to make object files into another directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

There are my main dir structure

```
push_swap
        |helpers/        -> *.c files
        |format_parsing/ -> *.c files
        |push_swaph/     -> push_swap.c, sort_a.c
        |libft/          -> *.c files, libft.h
        |ft_printf/      -> *.c files, libftprintf.h
        |includes/       -> header_push_swap.h          
______________________________________________________
```

In which method in a makefile i can create an object files from all *.c files and put them into another directory like objs/?

```
NAME         = push_swap
LIBFT        = libft.a
PRINTF       = libftprintf.a
HEADER       = includes/header_push_swap.h
LIBFTHEADER  = libft/libft.h
PRINTFHEADER = ft_printf/includes/header.h
OBJS_DIR     = objs/
SRC          = $(wildcard ./format_parsing/*.c) \
        $(wildcard ./helpers/*.c) \
        $(wildcard ./push_swaph/*.c)
OBJS         = $(SRC:.c=.o)
CC           = gcc
FLAGS        = -Wall -Wextra -Werror


all: $(NAME)

$(NAME) : $(LIBFTHEADER) $(PRINTFHEADER) $(LIBFT) $(PRINTF) $(OBJS)
    @$(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME)

$(LIBFT) :
    @cd ./libft && make

$(PRINTF) :
    @cd ./ft_printf/ && make


clean :
    @rm -rf $(OBJS_DIR)
    @rm -f $(OBJS)

fclean : clean
    @rm -rf $(OBJS)
    @cd ./libft/ && make fclean
    @cd ./ft_printf/ && make fclean
```

I made this makefile but it is still creates an object files inside of my C files directories.
And a second problem when i want to make $(NAME) it compiles all files and in last case it didn't found the references of functions in libft and ft_printf. But i put the header files also $(LIBFTHEADER) $(PRINTFHEADER).

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./format_parsing/parsing.o: in function `stack_nums_counter':
parsing.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `ft_strlen'
/usr/bin/ld: ./helpers/actions1.o: in function `pa':
actions1.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `ft_printf'
/usr/bin/ld: ./helpers/actions1.o: in function `pb':
actions1.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `ft_printf'
/usr/bin/ld: ./helpers/actions1.o: in function `ra':
actions1.c:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `ft_printf'
/usr/bin/ld: ./helpers/actions1.o: in function `rb':
actions1.c:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `ft_printf'
/usr/bin/ld: ./helpers/actions2.o: in function `rr':
actions2.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `ft_printf'
/usr/bin/ld: ./helpers/actions2.o:actions2.c:(.text+0x8e): more undefined references to `ft_printf' follow
/usr/bin/ld: ./helpers/helpers.o: in function `__store__':
helpers.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `ft_split'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `ft_atoi'
/usr/bin/ld: ./helpers/helpers.o: in function `__check__collection':
helpers.c:(.text+0x342): undefined reference to `ft_printf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:18: push_swap] Error 1
```

Comment: As an aside, littering your `Makefile` with `@`s is making it harder to debug your code, besides being hard on the eyes. Once it works, you can run it with `make -s` if you don't want to see what it's doing.

Comment: After `OBJS = $(SRC:.c=.o)` try adding: `OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJS_DIR), $(OBJS))` Note that you may need a rule to create the directory

Comment: Also, for recursive make consider "${MAKE} -C dir ..." instead of "cd dir && make ...". It knows how to pass command line flags, state, ...

Comment: When you try to implement a feature for the first time, it behooves you to start with *the simplest example* of that feature you can think of. In this case, one source file, one object file, no header files, no libraries, no `wildcard`, no recursion. It makes every aspect of the problem easier.

Comment: The easiest option is to specify your targets with a directory then use VPATH to find your source files.

Comment: @tripleee Agree re @.  Also, if you prefer silence (like I do) then set this environment variable `MAKEFLAGS=--silent`.

Comment: You should use `.PHONY: all clean fclean` to mark non-file targets.

Comment: Recursive make is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to specify the targets with directories and use VPATH to find the source files.  There is no way to test your supplied Makefile you didn't supply a minimal reproducible example so here is a skeleton instead:

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean
NAME = push_swap
VPATH = src

all: $(NAME)

clean:
    rm -f objs/* $(MAME)

$(NAME): objs/push_swap.o

objs/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

and create a couple of directories:

```
mkdir objs src
```

and an example src file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
int main(void) {
    printf("ok\n");
    return 1;
}
```

You can now run `make` and the object files end up objs, and in this case the binary in the top-level directory:

```
$ ls objs/* push_swap
ls: cannot access 'objs/*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'push_swap': No such file or directory
$ make
$ ls objs/* push_swap
objs/push_swap.o
push_swap
```